# Text File Data into PDF File using iText Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have successfully created Text file. and i need to add those text in to PDF.
its like i have everyday details in my text file. end of the month i need to generate pdf file with all the data.

what i have done here is

```
          try
              {
                 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("MonthlyReport.pdf"));
                 document.open();
                 document.add(new Paragraph("Month End Report."));
                 //Text file Data
                 try {
                        FileReader reader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt");
                        int character;

                        while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
                            document.add(new Paragraph((char) character));
                        }
                        reader.close();

                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }


                 //Text File Data


                 document.close();
                 writer.close();
              } catch (DocumentException exception)
              {
                 exception.printStackTrace();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
              {
                 exception.printStackTrace();
              }
```

But the problem is it only creates the `Month End Report` part only. i have already checked `FileReader` working or not and it works fine. i dont understand why it is not working inside with `document.add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was the problem. but after i replace FileReader with BufferReader. it worked fine

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyFile.txt")))
                {

                    String sCurrentLine;

                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        document.add(new Paragraph(sCurrentLine));
                    }

                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: A major difference is that you now read by line and not by character. Reading by character and generating a paragraph for each character obviously made no sense as all.